# Trying to load child component in react router v4 in switch tag

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load child component in react router, but in parent component it gives an error of props undefined.

//Here's my app.js file where child component is loaded.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar>
            <Router>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </Navbar>
</div>
</provider>
```

//Heres my code for navbar component.

```
const Navbar = ({ props, auth }) =>  ({
        render() {

            const authLinks = (
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li className="current"><a href="#intro">Auth Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Service</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            );

            const guestLinks = (
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li className="current"><Link to="/">Guest Home</Link></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Service</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            );
            return (
            <Fragment>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                            <span className="sr-only">Toggle nav</span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">VDOXON</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="navigation collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    {auth.isAuthenticated ? (authLinks) : (guestLinks)}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div className='container'>
            {props.children}
            </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
        }
    })
```

//Can anyone tell me the exact the way to load the child component into a main component while routing in react.

Comment: When you're rendering your Navbar component, you're not passing either 'props' OR 'auth' props in your app file. That's why it's erroring on 'props' not being defined when you're trying to access it within the Navbar component

Comment: the auth prop is coming from state and is working fine, and as for props i guess i am passing the landing component as a child prop to navbar component when switching the route. If not , then can you suggest me how to pass landing component as a prop to navbar at "/" route

Comment: The landing component would be a child of the React Router Switch, based on your route. The error might be your syntax with the Navbar. You're writing const `Navbar = ({ props, auth })` which is expecting props to be a key in the passed object. If you'd like to deconstruct the object to get auth, but have the rest of the props in the object, you can do `({ auth, ...props })`